# Question involving the law of total probability

Tags: probability, statistics

I am currently revising for an exam and am a bit stuck on this question and how to tackle it? I assume I need to use the law of total probability but am unsure where to start? Thanks

So far I had written P(Positive) = P(positive|infected)*P(infected) + P(positive|not infected)* P(not infected)

where P(not infected) and P(infected) both equal 1/2? Is this okay?

[image]

Comment: Your approach is correct, your assumed infection statistics is not. The correct figures (one of them) are given in the problem description !

Comment: How many people are carrying the virus (i.e. is infected) according to the problem description?

Comment: Law of total probability for (a). Standard application of Bayes' Theorem for (b). Usual jargon: Sensitivity is 98%, specificity is (100 - 0.7)%. Wikipedia on 'sensitivity' and 'specificity' has nice graphics. (Plus roughly half a million similar Q&A's on this site. Of course, I exaggerate, but still....)

Comment: Hint: $P(\texttt{"infected"})=1\%$

Comment: So P(infected) = 0.01 and P(not infected) = 0.99?

Answer (score 0):

a) The probability of a randomly chosen person being infected, $$\mathbf{P_i = 0.01}$$ and therefore the probability of a person not being infected $$\mathbf{P_\bar i = 0.99}$$ Also, the probability of a positive result for an infected person, $$\mathbf{P_{P_i} = 0.98}$$ and a positive result for an uninfected person $$\mathbf{P_{P_\bar i} = 0.007}$$Now using Law of Total Probability, the probability of the test showing positive on a randomly chosen person is given by $$\mathbf{P_P = P_{P_i}\times P_i + P_{P_\bar i}\times P_\bar i}$$ $$\mathbf{= 0.98 \times 0.01 + 0.007 \times 0.99}$$ $$\mathbf{=0.01673}$$

b) From Bayes' Theorem, the probability that the person is infected given he shows a positive result, $$\mathbf{P_{i_P} = \frac{P_{P_i}\times P_i}{P_P}}$$
$$\mathbf{=\frac{0.98\times 0.01}{0.01673}}$$ $$\mathbf{=0.585}$$